# Calling Functions across the project

Tags: vb.net

Are there any functions that can be called across the project.

I mean we cn use Private Sub ABC() function in the document where it has been declared but is there any way that this could be called from any other form?

Thanks

Furqan

Comment: Please consider marking an answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider adding a `Shared` tag in your Sub method.

Comment: Does not work.  Build fails saying ABC not declared (in form2)

Answer (score 1):

You could mark it `Friend` rather than `Private`, and then use the [`InternalsVisibleTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute to give access to other projects.

Answer (score 1):

In VB, this is typically done via a Module.  It can also be done using a Shared Public/Friend accessor (in which case you have to access it using class.method instead of instance.method).

Modules are basically singletons, and that is disliked by some, and can cause problems when refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't call Private Sub declared in a class by another class. Use Public Sub instead.

Comment: I declared Public Sub ABC() in form1 and called it in Form2 by Call ABC() but it says ABC() is not declared.  How to fix it?

Comment: @@user415037: No code huh? But you said: `I declared Public Sub ABC() in form1 and called it in Form2 by Call ABC() but it says ABC() is not declared.`

Comment: Yes that is right.  I just put a message box inside ABC() to test if it works.  My idea is to show that message box on Form2 when the ABC() is called.

Comment: @user415037: Actually I will test your code in Visual Studio and propose a real solution that works for you. But without the code, I can't do anything because I'm very tired (mentally) today. Maybe other people can help you.

Answer (score 0):

To call the abc function from form2 you need to 2 things

1.) make function as shared

2.) create an object of form1 in form2 then call by using the object